# create svn project in subfolder

Tags: svn

I have SVN server https://blabla.com/svn. I have range op projects that are related on the same theme and I'm thinking about creating folder in SVN called related_projects and projects must be placed in this folder like this:

```
https://blabla.com/svn/related_projects/project1
https://blabla.com/svn/related_projects/project2
https://blabla.com/svn/related_projects/projectN
```

Is it possible to make like this? Our system administrator  tells that nobody does like this? But why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. That looks ALMOST like the "multiple projects" example at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout . I don't actually see a reason for the extra subdirectory "related_projects"; most of the time you just put all the projects in your repository side-by-side. But nothing stops you from creating extra subdirectories to your heart's content. If you have an existing repository with "trunk", "tags", and "branches" directly under the repository root, I guess it might make some sense to add new projects in a subdirectory.